# Display Information from Api Call React

Tags: reactjs, forms, api, state

I'm new to React and trying to display the raw data from an Api Call for a word from Merriam Webster. I've successfully updated the state and I receive the information in the console. However, I'm not sure how to display it on the page. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MerriamAPI from '../services/MerriamAPI';

class Search extends Component {

state = {
  word: '',
  info: [],
}

handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({word:event.target.value.toLowerCase()})
}


handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var word = this.state.word.trim();
  const data = await MerriamAPI.getWordInfo(word);
  this.setState({info: data})
  console.log(this.state.info[0].shortdef)
}
render (){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
        <p>
          {this.state.info.map((info) => <p key={info[0].meta.id}>{...info}</p>)} 
        </p>
      </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Data from Merriam Webster API. I'm trying to display the shortdef.
[image]

Comment: can you upload how `data ` looks like?

Comment: I just added a pic of the data. I'm trying to display the "shortdef"

Answer (score 0):

your component will be re-rendered, as component's state updated.

so you just need to write your component just to display what you want

```
...
render (){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
        <p>
          {this.state.info}
        </p>
        <p>{this.state.word}</p>
      </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

if you want to display array of data, you can do like this

```
render () {
  return (
    ...
    // assume each element in someArrayData is unique and not an object.
    <div>{this.state.someArrayData.map(item => <p key={item}>{item}</p>)}</div>
  )
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Thank you, I tried tinkering around a bit and couldn't figure it out. Your explanation makes sense but now I think it's because I'm not mapping over the data correctly. I added a picture for reference. Here is what code I tried:   `{this.state.info.map((info) => <p key={info[0].meta.id}>{...info}</p>)}`

Comment: can you describe how `info` looks like? if it is object, it won't be rendered right.

Comment: Hi @gnujoow, here is a link to the data I'm working with. There's multiple arrays and objects. https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/code?key=220d665c-3a1e-471c-b62c-283c84e1e8f3

Comment: if you just want to print out specific string by using its key. or if you want to print out all memebers of the obejct, using `JSON.stringify()` would be the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
render (){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
        <p>
          {this.state.info.length ? this.state.info.map((item, key) => (
            <p key={key}>{item.shortdef}</p>)
          )) :null} 
        </p>
      </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Majid I tried it but I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined

Comment: you can do this
1.```<p key={item.meta.id}>{item.shortdef}</p>)```
or
2.
`{this.state.info.length ? this.state.info.map((item, key) => (<p key={key}>{item.shortdef}</p>))) :null} `